# Relation between ramification locus of a tower and of it's constant field extension

Tags: function-fields, ramification

I am trying to understand  *Remark 7.2.22 (Page 256)* of *Algebraic Function Fields and Codes* (Second Edition) by *Henning Stichtenoth*.

In that remark he considers a tower $\mathcal{F} = (F_0,F_1,F_2,\dots)$ over a finite constant field $\mathbb{F_q}$ and extends it constantly with $L$ to get $\mathcal{F'}=(F_0',F_1',F_2',\dots)$ (i.e. $L/\mathbb{F_q}$ is an algebraic extension (may be finite or infinite) and $F_i' = F_iL$ $\forall i \geq 1$).

Next he takes

> a place $P \in \mathbb{P}(F_i)$ for some $i >0$ and asserts that $P$ ramifies in the extension $F_{i+1}/F_i$ if and only if the places $P' \in \mathbb{P}(F_i')$ lying above $P$ are ramified in the extension $F_{i+1}'/F_i'$.

My doubt here is if the situation is as given below

**Case 1:**
$$
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
F_i' & \rightarrow & F_{i+1}' &&P'&\rightarrow & P_1'\\
\uparrow & & \uparrow && \uparrow && \uparrow\\
F_i& \rightarrow & F_{i+1} && P &\xrightarrow{e>1} & P_1
\end{array}
 $$
(where $e$ is the corresponding ramification index in the diagram) then as $e(P'/P)=e(P_1'/P_1)=1$ we can say that $e(P_1'/P')=e(P_1/P) >1$.

But what if the situation as depicted in the following diagram also happens

**Case 2:**
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
Q & \rightarrow & P_2'\\
\uparrow && \uparrow \\
P & \xrightarrow{e=1} & P_2
\end{array}
$$
i.e. $P_1, P_2$ both extend $P$ with one extension ramified and another unramified. In this case $e(P_2'|Q)$ has to be equal to $1$.

How can he conclude that every place $P' \in \mathbb{P}(F_i')$ gets ramified if $P$ is ramified? Doesn't **Case 2** situation arise?

Comment: The ramification is multiplicative, and the vertical ramification indices are $1$ (constant field extensions), so the horizontal ramification indices agree. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right but here we have two cases together two places lying above P, one ramified and the other unramified, still we say that P is ramified because e(P1/P)>1. The question is what is the guarantee that Q is also ramified because that's what if and only if condition tells? I could not understand that part.   I am editing the question to highlight the statement.

Comment: You are right, I understand now the subtlety involved. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following definition (item (b) of Definition 3.5.4 in Stichtenoth's book):

**Definition:** Given an algebraic field extension $F'/F$, a place $P\in\mathbb P(F)$ is said to be *ramified* if $e(P'|P)>1$ for **some** place $P\in\mathbb P(F')$ above $P$ .

Let $F_i, F_i'$ as in your question, and let $P\in\mathbb P(F_i)$. We want to show that $P$ is ramified in $F_{i+1}/F_i$ iff $P'\in\mathbb P(F_i')$ is ramified in $F_{i+1}'/F_i$ **for all** $\boldsymbol{P'}$ **above** $\boldsymbol P$.

Suppose then that $P$ is ramified in $F_{i+1}/F_i$. Then there is a place $P_1\in\mathbb P(F_i')$ above $P$ such that $e(P_1|P)>1$. Let $P'$ be **any** place in $\mathbb P(F_i')$ above $P$. We want to find a place $P_1'\in\mathbb P(F_{i+1}')$ above $P'$ such that $e(P_1'|P')>1$.

We want to use the existence of the place $P_1$; more concretely, if we are able to find $P_1'$ simultaneously above $P'$ and $P_1$, then we are done, because in this case

$$e(P_1'|P')e(P'|P)=e(P_1'|P_1'\cap F_{i+1})e(P_1'\cap F_{i+1}|P)\,,\tag{$\ast$}$$

and since $e(P'|P)=e(P_1'|P_1'\cap F_{i+1})=1$ (constant field extensions), it follows that $e(P_1'|P')=e(P_1'\cap F_{i+1}|P)=e(P_1|P)>1$.

If $F_i'$ and $F_{i+1}$ were linearly disjoint over $F_i'\cap F_{i+1}$, then we can use the following result:

**Lemma:** Let $F_1,F_2$ be function fields over a perfect field $k$. Suppose that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are linearly disjoint over $F=F_1\cap F_2$, and let $P\in\mathbb P(F)$ and $P_i\in\mathbb P(F_i)$ for $i=1,2$ be places such that $P_1|P$ and $P_2|P$. If the compositum $F_1F_2$ is defined, then exists a place $Q\in\mathbb P(F_1F_2)$ such that $Q|P_1$ and $Q|P_2$.

This result appears as Lemma 2.1.3 in Jörg Wulftange's PhD Thesis, which can be found [here](http://duepublico.uni-duisburg-essen.de/servlets/DerivateServlet/Derivate-11279/dissertation.pdf). I strongly believe that this hypothesis is satisfied in your case, but I am too lazy now to think about it.

For the converse, if $P$ is unramified in $F_{i+1}/F_i$, then $e(P_1|P)=1$ for **all** $P_1\in\mathbb P(F_{i+1})$ above $P$, so for any $P'\in\mathbb P(F_i')$ above $P$ and **any** $P_1'\in\mathbb P(F_{i+1}')$ above $P'$ we have $e(P_1'|P')=1$ (do the same reasoning as in $(\ast)$ above).

Comment: Your theorem statement differs from that of the Stichtenoth's. His statement says that every place $P_1$ of $F_i'$ lying over P ramifies if P is ramified in $F_{i+1}/F_i$ as I have highlighted in my statement. This can be confirmed from Stichtenoth's book page 256 (second edition) where he goes on to declare $$Ram(\mathcal{F}'/F_0') = \{ P' \in \mathbb{P}(F_0') |  P' \cap F_0 \in Ram(\mathcal{F}/F_0) \}$$. He is actually saying that you don't have to look for simultaneous place containing both $P'$ and $P_1$, any place above $P$ works. That is my problem.

Comment: I am reversing your editing, and I am going to rewrite my argument a little: perhaps I was not clear enough, sorry.

Comment: Any how as  "Matthias Wendt" pointed out in [http://mathoverflow.net/questions/222221/relation-between-ramification-locus-of-a-tower-and-of-its-constant-field-extensi] that $L/\mathbb{F}_q$ will be Galois (I am not sure if it is an infinite extension) which implies that $F_{i}'/F_i$ is Galois therefore every place lying above $P$ has same ramification index. Therefore the statement follows.

Comment: @bharath Indeed: $L/\mathbb F_q$ being Galois solves it all...

Comment: I am sorry @Chibchas. The problem is not yet solved. "Matthias Wendt" suggestion only tells that $F_i'/F_i$ is Galois. Therefore the places lying above $P$ in $F_i'$ has same ramification index. But this is obvious as I have mentioned already that it is just a constant extension and therefore P is unramified in  $F_i'/F_i$. But we are talking about $F_{i+1}'/F_i'$ (which is not necessarily Galois). So the problem is still there if we don't assume that $F_{i+1}/F_i$ is Galois.

Comment: @bharath Then try to follow my suggestion, namely, to prove that the extensions involved are in fact linearly disjoint (guess what? I am still lazy to think about it :P )